# Shiny-Split selectsizeinput for each element

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

I am new to R and i am trying to make an interactive app.

i am using selectsizeinput to select state names but i don't know how to get each one from the user input to go through my data set and get the rest of the rest of the data

```
selectizeInput('selectedStates', 'Select states', choices = state.name, multiple = TRUE,options = list(maxItems = 5))
```

Comment: `input$selectedStates` ??

Comment: @BigDataScientist thanks i was working around input[['selectedStates']]